# Book series about a kid's journey to the center of the Earth where he finds the Earth is an alien ship or something

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading this story when I was in middle school and can't seem the find what the series was called. The main character digs a hole and finds an underground city, from which he is banished and​ travels deeper and deeper into the Earth.

Eventually, the get to the center of the Earth, which is hollow and has a star in the middle and find an alien race (who are trying to reproduce by laying eggs inside humans?). Not 100% sure about that last part but I think that was what happened.

Also I think they said the Earth was like a ship​ or something for the aliens, but I don't remember too well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Nice question, but you can probably still give us some more details; when were you in middle school?  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking a good question.

Comment: The Tunnels series

Comment: @Adamant missed the answer box there :p

Comment: too lazy too busy. you do it

Comment: While we're waiting or someone to post it as an answer, here's a link to [the Wikipedia article on *The Tunnels series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnels_(novel)). I haven't read it but it certainly looks like the book you are asking about,

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @Adamant in the comments, this is most likely the *Tunnels* series by Roderick Gordon (started in 2007, six books total).

Summary of the first one, from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1175893.Tunnels):

> 14-year-old Will Burrows has little in common with his strange, dysfunctional family. In fact, the only bond he shares with his eccentric father is a passion for archaeological excavation. So when his dad mysteriously vanishes, Will is compelled to dig up the truth behind his disappearance. He unearths the unbelievable: a subterranean society that time forgot. "The Colony" has existed unchanged for a century, but it's no benign time capsule of a bygone era. Because the Colony is ruled by a merciless overclass, the Styx. Will must free his father--is he also about to ignite a revolution?

[TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Tunnels) confirms the eggs part, as well as the Earth being a ship:

> [Bizarre Alien Reproduction](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BizarreAlienReproduction): The Styx appear to reproduce like their hosts for the most part—they can even interbreed with the host species, because, just like Xenomorphs, they use the host's DNA to modify their own appearances to look just like them. During the phase the females instead produce eggs on their own and implant them into hosts from other species, creating warrior caste Styx. They can also produce Armagi, which are all male, but also multiply by planting eggs in a similar way. [...]
>
> [Planet Spaceship](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlanetSpaceship): Earth itself turns out to be one at the conclusion of Terminal.